# Cocos2d+pybox2d vs Cocos2d-Iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, python, cocos2d, tiles

Myself and two colleagues are working on making our first indie game for PC and, we decided to use Cocos2D + PyBox2D.  We decided this based on what we've seen of Cocos2D-iPhone games, but I'm not sure if Cocos2D-iPhone is just a port of the Python version with a few more features, or if it's far more advanced than the Python version.

I just want to be sure that I'm on the right track. (We also want to port our game to Android and iPhone if it is successful on the PC.)

Note: For the maps we will use Tiled , which is compatible with Cocos2D (both iPhone and Python versions, I think.)

Comment: They are both very similar; the problem you are going to have is porting the Python side. (if you get to that; but don't put it in the way)

Comment: @Communist Duck: Cocos2D for Python was the predecessor of Cocos2D-iPhone, so while they're similar, the Python version isn't nearly as full-featured as the Cocos2D-iPhone is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey there, I think that Cocos2d-iPhone is far more advanced and full-featured than Cocos2D-Python. Some design decisions are the same, like using a SceneGraph, and they share some class names, but I would bet that Cocos2d-iPhone has far more work behind it than Cocos2D-Python. I would perhaps recommend that you use [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/).  It is a C++ port of Cocos2D, which has cross-platform support as its main feature.

Comment: But it does support Linux ? I see that it can be use in many moviles and win32 but not in linux as far as i read. Thanks for the answer i keep searching.

Comment: @DraskyVanderhoff: You are correct; cocos2d-x only support Windows.  Cocos2D-iPhone, however, supports Mac OS X as well as iPhone.  You MIGHT be able to get Cocos2D-iPhone to compile for Linux using something like the [Cocotron toolchain](http://www.cocotron.org/), but it would be a lot of work.

Comment: @Drasky: I'd just like to add that if you want to be able to easily build your game for iPhone, Android, and PC using a Cocos2D-style engine, then Cocos2D-x is really your best bet.  If you decide you're only interested in mobile development, you could also try something like [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/).  To be honest, though, I don't think you'll have much luck finding a solution that works for Linux as well as Android and iPhone.  Do let us know if you do find something, though!

Comment: seems to be available on linux now http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_to_run_HelloWorld_and_tests_on_linux